# Simplifying conditional expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, conditional

I have an expression of the form

```
ConditionalExpression[I a + y1, {True, True, True, True}]
```

as a result of some computation. (The expected answer is just `I a + y1`.) Even if I put

```
ConditionalExpression[I a + y1, {True, True, True, True}] // Simplify
```

the result does not simplify. How can I simplify this expression?

By the way, the above expression is obtained by the following code (in Mathematica 13):

```
$Assumptions = {k1 > 0, k2 > 0, a > 0, m > 0};
G[x_] = (x + I a)^3;
exp = Exp[-I k2 z1] Exp[-I k1 z2] Exp[I k2 y1] Exp[I k1 y2] (
  G[z2 - y1] G[z1 - y2])/(G[z2 - z1] G[z2 - y2] G[z1 - y1] G[y1 - y2]);
poles = FunctionPoles[exp, y2] // Simplify
```

Comment: `ConditionalExpression[I a + y1, {True, True, True, True}] // Normal` or `ConditionalExpression[I a + y1, {True, True, True, True}] /. 
 list_List :> And @@ list`

Comment: @BobHanlon It works. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `ConditionalExpression[I a + y1, {True, True, True, True}][[1]]`

Comment: Use `$Assumptions = k1>0 && k2>0 && a>0 && m>0` instead.